# PackageId:Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.WMIProvider;PackageAction:Install;ReturnCode:1722;

Tags: visual-studio

I am trying to install Visual Studio 2019. But It gives this error:

```
PackageId:Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.WMIProvider;PackageAction:Install;ReturnCode:1722;
```

How can I fix this error?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I installed Visual Studio 2019 community edition.

It was about installation driver issue.

So double check regedit `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion` default installation path for windows application.

So I mean my `ProgramW6432Dir`'s value was only `C:\`. I changed it to `C:\Program Files`

1. check regedit
   `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion`
   default installation drivers paths. If it is not correct fix it.
2. Restart the windows OS.
3. Uninstall `Visual Studio Installer` and `Visual Studio 2019`.
4. Retry installation process.

Answer (score 0):

For me, one of these answers helped: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1038410/packageidmicrosoftvisualstudiosetupwmiproviderpack-11.html

The one with putting in msiexec at the command prompt. You may have to change the version number, though.